# Convolution integral for LTI system

Tags: signal-theory, convolution

We know that any continuous time signal can be expressed as follows: 
$$x(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(τ)δ(t-τ)dτ$$
I came across a certain relation regarding linear time invariant systems . Using $$x(t)*δ(t)=x(t)$$ we get , since it's an LTI system : $$x(t)*δ(t-t_0)=x(t-t_0)$$
How did we get here? Is there a property I'm not aware of?  I try to imagine the convolution graphically and since we have the x(t) how can  the multiplication with the dirac function give x(t-t0) for every point in the convolution integral?

Comment: Just substitute `t` with `t-t0` in the integral equation and you will get it. Even without solving the integral...

Comment: The dirac delta is also called 'the selection function'. You don't get x(t-t0) for every point in the convolution integral, just at t-t0, and zero everywhere else, so the whole convolution comes out to be x(t-t0). It's one of those mathematical things that I regard as a cheat, the dirac delta definition gives it this property, which is consistent when you flog through the convolution. Remember the dirac delta is not something you can draw, it's infinitely high at (0), but with a unity area under it, not very physical, very contrived.

Comment: @Neil_UK So you should consider `i` and even negatives as cheats. I call them *abstractions*. And very useful ones.

Comment: @EugeneSh. No, i, quarternions, and octonians are all useful, but the relation \$e^{i \pi}=-1\$ says more about the construction of the number system than it says about the symbols themselves, so that's a cheat as well in my terms. My complaint with the dirac delta is that it's designed to do a specific job, and it can't be drawn, only described. It's like the difference between infinities, it gets a bit, silly really. I'm happier with integration Lebegue style.

Comment: @Neil_UK It's a bit primitive to consider anything you can't draw as a non-existent or "cheat" in my opinion, sorry. Difference between infinities *does* exist. Quantum mechanics *is* working. Even though it is described using mostly these "cheats" and cannot be imagined or understood by most (if not all). The whole Math is a tool designed for a specific job. And the fact you *can* draw some stuff in it is completely accidental.

Comment: @Neil_UK It may not be possible to draw it accurately without a sheet of infinitely high paper but, hey, you can get away with it using a sheet of A4 and a little imagination! The graphical realisation is much more informative and educationally useful than a blinkered solution of the convolution integral. That can come later, when we understand what convolution really does.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I said I *regarded* it as a cheat, I didn't say it *was* a cheat. This is a useful discussion, helping me tease out what I really mean. In DSP, functions we convolve have an amplitude we can measure, for instance a voltage waveform with an ADC. Delta has amplitude in a different sense, it can't be captured on an ADC, we have to change the physical world's rules to handle the convolution. That's why it's OK in a maths course, but I get uneasy if it's snuck into a DSP course, This is an engineering site, not maths. I'm cool with QE, where did you think I wasn't?

Comment: @Neil_UK OK, I guess it's just a different meaning of the "cheat" thing we are using. Anyway, wrt to QM I just used it as an example for a whole field built mostly on top of these "cheats", yet seem to be a real thing.

Comment: @EugeneSh. An example of a total and unmitigated cheat is the Banach-Tarski dissection. Redefines what 'volume' means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*How can the multiplication with the dirac function give x(t-t0) of every point in the convolution integral?*

It can't, that is what the integral does.

> -- I try to imagine the convolution graphically.

This is very helpful, but inside the integral, it is unnecessary.
Inside the integral it is just multiplication.
The integral operation handles the infinite summation for all values
of tau.

So I agree, the multiplication cannot get every point, that is why the
integral is needed.

If you find a good video/gif of convolution
[some here,](http://bmia.bmt.tue.nl/education/courses/fev/course/notebooks/Convolution.html)
you can think of each frame as the multiplication for a particular
tau.  The combined effect is the integration.

Hope that helps connect the visual to the equation.

Answer (score 0):

A convolution is simply reversing one of the signals w.r.t the vertical (y(t)) axis and then  shifting it towards the right, left  continously till it reaches infinity at both the ends.in that process the signals comes across the other unshifted signal once and crossesthrough it.while doing so, at each instant it will have some common area,the plot of this common area is the convolution signal output.Now, If we take the impulse function in the same way,the common area will be simply get the other stationery signal.but, if we take a shifted version of the impulse in the same way,again we get the same unshifted signal as the common area but,at a different instant of time compared to earlier output,the reason is that,initially we have shifted by some t0 the impulse and started the sliding ..so the difference in time of the outputs is equal to the difference of intial shift of the impulse.